# Adding a value in a custom property of a CAD file gives me a type mismatch error

Tags: c#, solidworksapi

In my scenario, the custom property is first present on the CAD file with the type `SolidWorks.Interop.swconst.swCustomInfoType_e.swCustomInfoText`. Then, I delete it to re-added it as the same type

Here's the code sample

```
propertyManager.Get6("Order_size", false, out var value, out var resolvedValOut, out var wasResolved, out var linkProperty);
propertyManager.Delete2("Order_size");
var result = propertyManager.Add3("Order_size", 30, "MyValue", (int)swCustomPropertyAddOption_e.swCustomPropertyDeleteAndAdd);
```

When calling the *Add3* function, this is the result I get: *3* that can be translate to "Specified value of the custom property does not match the specified type" ([source](https://help.solidworks.com/2019/english/api/swconst/SolidWorks.Interop.swconst%7ESolidWorks.Interop.swconst.swCustomInfoAddResult_e.html))

That error only happens for 1 property in a loop that contains many other with the same type.

- Tested Solidwork version: 2022 and 2019.
- Tested Solidwork interop version: 23 and 33
- The property is not marked as link to others in the document

**My question**: Why do I get this error from my code? I have tried multiple values to assigned to the property.

UPDATE: The CAD is an assembly

Comment: I have seen exact same problem and to be honest, not sure why it happens. But if you open this file you might see a red cell in the corner of the custom property grid - just double click on this or simply click on the grid top-right cell - it fixed the problem for me.

Comment: @Artem In the assembly CAD, I openned the "File Property" -> "Custom Tab" and there's no exclamation mark. It's the same in the "Confugration Property" tab and in the "Properties Summary". I did select all the item in the "Configuration Properties" tab and the "Properties Summary" tab.